# Let $V$ be p-torsion representation. Then, $H^n(K,V)＝0$ for all $n≧3$ in the context of class field theory

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, homology-cohomology, p-adic-number-theory, class-field-theory

> Let $V$ be p-torsion representation. Then, $H^n(K,V)＝0$ for all $n≧3$,
> where $K$ is absolute Galois group of $\Bbb {Q_p}$.

I heard this is **classical** result of **class field theory**, but also proved without using class field theory **via theory of $(φ,Γ)$modules**.

But I have never met this statement **in the context of class field theory**.
Could you give me reference or self-contained explanation of the proof of the titled statement in the context of class field theory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Serre's *Galois cohomology*, proposition II.2.4 for the following statement:

**Proposition** Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $\neq p$, and let $n$ be an integer $\geq 1$. Then the following conditions are equivalent:

- $\operatorname{cd}_p(G_k) \leq n$, where $\operatorname{cd}_p$ denotes the $p$-cohomological dimension.
- For any separable finite extension $K/k$, we have $H^{n+1}(K, \Bbb G_m)=0$ and $H^n(K,\Bbb G_m)$ is $p$-divisible.

Now one important theorem of local class field theory is that $H^2(K,\Bbb G_m)\cong \Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ for a local field $K$, which is divisible.
Another important theorem for class field theory is [Tate's theorem in group cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_formation#Tate%27s_theorem_and_the_Artin_map) which implies that $$H^3(K,\Bbb G_m) \cong H^1(K,\Bbb Z)=\mathrm{Hom}_{cont}(G_K,\Bbb Z)=0$$

Comment: Thank you for your perfect answer. But I checked Serre's Galois cohomology, then, may be the proposition seems like prop11 of 3.1 of this version,file:///Users/shigaasuka/Downloads/Galois%20Cohomology%20by%20Jean-Pierre%20Serre%20(auth.)%20(z-lib.org).pdf,right ?

Comment: @kleinfour I can't access a file on your computer, but maybe there are different editions of the book? I have the corrected second printing from 2002. Note that I simplified the proposition a bit, Serre acutally proves a stronger statement.